# Youtube Subscribe Button Redirect

Tags: redirect, youtube

Youtube gives its channels a subscribe button that is clickable and does not lead to anywhere it just lets you know you subscribe. I want once it lets you know you have subscribe to re direct you to a new webpage...

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCvoMfs-F49kmEeIWzZ0m2bA" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>
```

Pleas Help

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: here it is forgot to post it